# Black boxes around iframe video embed

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code provided by imgur to try to give my website a full background gif.

```
<iframe class="imgur-embed" width="100%" height="1080" frameborder="0" src="https://i.imgur.com/eePBC12.gifv#embed"></iframe>
```

Here is the link to the gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUuOU.jpg

The issue is it creates black boxes around the top and bottom of the background.I just want a full background gif:
[Incorrect background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9sFX.jpg)

I've tried manipulating the width/height of the image, I couldn't find anything on black boxes while using iframe that resembled my problem so I was hoping I could get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an ordinary image. .gifv files aren't real images, so you'll have to use the .gif version:

```
html {
    background-image: https://i.imgur.com/eePBC12.gif
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also added background-size: cover;